# Powershell Script to Replace Text in Text File, but not save to new file

Tags: powershell, file-io, large-data, in-place

I am trying to replace text in a large text file, 5gb. I found the script below. It outputs to a new file.

```
powershell -Command "(gc myFile.txt) -replace 'foo', 'bar' | Out-File -encoding ASCII myFile.txt"
```

I am trying not to create another file because of the size. How do I replace text in a text file without saving it to a new file.

Comment: Please describe what happens when you run this?

Comment: When I run it it replace the text just fine... but it creates a new file

Comment: i doubt this works with a 5gb file, it would throw @ 2gb as thats array max size

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, the limit you mention only applies to the array object _itself_ (and fundamentally only applies to Windows PowerShell / .NET Framework), it doesn't include the size of the strings that the array elements _reference_. E.g., `$arr3gb = 1..3 | ForEach-Object { 'x' * 512mb + $_ }` works fine in Windows PowerShell too: while the size of the array _plus its elements_ is 3GB+ (each `[char]` is 2 bytes), the array itself is small, because its elements store only _references_ to the strings, which are each the size of `[IntPtr]::Size`, i.e. 8 bytes on 64-bit platforms.

Comment: While your question is self-contradictory, it does imply interesting challenges, making it of potential interest to future readers. Therefore, your feedback would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I replace text in a text file without saving it to a new file?

The command in your question -
`(gc myFile.txt) -replace 'foo', 'bar' | Out-File -encoding ASCII myFile.txt` - ***does* write to the *same file*, although it rewrites *the entire content*** of the file.

It is able to do so, because enclosing the `gc` ([`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)) call in `(...)` ensures that the *entire content is read into memory first.*

While this may be slow and memory-intensive and bears a hypothetical risk of data loss, it does allow you to write back to the same file.

Note that with an ASCII-encoded input file that is 5GB in size, you'll need 10GB+ of available memory to even read the lines of the file into memory (on disk, each characters is a *single byte*, in memory, every `[char]` instance occupies *2 bytes*), including a varying amount of memory depending on how many lines are affected by *actual replacements* (via [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator), which passes a given input string through if there's no match).

If you do have enough memory, you can **greatly speed up your command** as follows (leaving the `powershell -Command` call aside):

```bash
Set-Content -Encoding Ascii myFile.txt -Value (
  (Get-Content -ReadCount 0 myFile.txt) -replace 'foo', 'bar'
)
```

---

The only way to **avoid having to rewrite the file *in full*** is if (a) the search regex always matches a *fixed number of characters*, and (b) the substitution (replacement) text is the *exact same length*.
If you were to write to a file with a *variable*-width encoding such as UTF-8, the *encoded* form of both strings would have to have the exact same *byte count*.

You could then read the file in *binary* mode, and overwrite only the bytes of interest.

Needless to say, this would require much more effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
powershell -Command "(gc myFile.txt) -replace 'foo', 'bar' | set-content myFile.txt -encoding ASCII"
```

Comment: The only difference between your command and the OP's is the use of `Set-Content` instead of `Out-File`. Can you explain why you would expect that to make a difference (other than providing a slight performance gain)?

Comment: It seemed to me that in this case a temporary file is not created, but an operation is performed on the current one. Am I wrong?

Comment: You're not wrong, but that to me that requires a very different framing of your answer, to avoid confusion; along the lines of: "Unlike what you state, the command in your question doesn't create a new file, i.e. it already directly writes back to the input file. _Incidentally_, you can speed up the command a bit by using `Set-Content` rather than `Out-File`." As an aside: this speedup is not dramatic - additional, dramatic optimizations are possible.

Comment: yes, I already learned about them from your answer below))